# Breaking 32 bit long into 4 bytes

Tags: c

I know there are a lot of examples for this, but NONE of them are working. pPtr is a pointer to a temporary log of this type

```
typedef struct
{
  TIMESTAMP_TYPE oTimeStamp;
  ASSERT_ID_TYPE ucAssertID;
  Int16 iData1;
  Int16 iData2;
  UInt16 uiChecksum;
} 
LOG_ENTRY_TYPE;
```

where I dequeue my log when there is one I want to store off to EEEPROM.
oTimestamp is of type

```
typedef struct  
{
  UInt32 ulSecond;  
  UInt16 usMilliSecond;
  UInt16 usPowerCycleCount; 

 } 
  TIMESTAMP_TYPE;
```

All of the other accesses and writes work, even for milliseconds, but I cannot get the seconds timestamp value broken down into 4 bytes.

Here is what I have tried (obviously with only one version uncommented out):

```
 UChar tmpByteHigh;
 UChar tmpByteLow;

//Attempt1
tmpByteHigh = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond >> 24) & 0x000000FF;
SPIwrite(tmpByteHigh);  
tmpByteLow = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
SPIwrite(tmpByteLow);
tmpByteHigh = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond >> 8) & 0x000000FF;
SPIwrite(tmpByteHigh);
tmpByteLow = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond) & 0x000000FF;
SPIwrite(tmpByteLow);

//Attempt 2
tmpByteHigh = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond & 0xFF000000UL) >> 24;
SPIwrite(tmpByteHigh);
tmpByteLow = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond & 0x00FF0000UL)  >> 16;
SPIwrite(tmpByteLow);
tmpByteHigh = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond & 0x0000FF00UL) >> 8;
SPIwrite(tmpByteHigh);
tmpByteLow = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond) & 0x000000FFUL;
SPIwrite(tmpByteLow);


//Attempt 3
//get msw from 32 bit value and write the 2 msB from it
tmpWord = (pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF;
tmpByteHigh = (tmpWord >> 8) & 0x00FF;
SPIwrite(tmpByteHigh);
tmpByteLow = tmpWord & 0x00FF;
SPIwrite(tmpByteLow);
//get lsw from 32 bit value and write the 2 lsB from it
tmpWord = pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond & 0x0000FFFF;
tmpByteHigh = (tmpWord >> 8) & 0x00FF;
SPIwrite(tmpByteHigh);
tmpByteLow = tmpWord & 0x00FF;
SPIwrite(tmpByteLow);


//Attempt 4
UChar* myPointer = (UChar*)&pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond;
UChar myArray[4];
myArray[0]=myPointer[0];
myArray[1]=myPointer[1];
myArray[2]=myPointer[2];
myArray[3]=myPointer[3];
SPIwrite(myArray[0]);
SPIwrite(myArray[1]);
SPIwrite(myArray[2]);
SPIwrite(myArray[3]);
```

Each and every time I get 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x80 sent over SPI.  Any thoughts?  Be easy on me I am not a great programmer.

Comment: ... and what is the expected output?

Comment: Thoughts? Yes. You have a wrong data inside your `pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond`. Or a bug in `SPIwrite`. Because the conversion code is fine.

Comment: Maybe `pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond` is really equal to `0x80000000`? You proved that in 4 different ways; seems a pretty solid proof.

Comment: Ok, I thought it might be wrong data in the .ulSecond spot, but since all other data was good I was skeptical.  How bout thoughts on why the .ulSecond data would be faulty when all other data is fine?  I dont know why the seconds data would be faulty when the milliseconds and powercycleCount data are fine....

Comment: Have you done a test/example program that includes assignments of literal values (`pPtr->oTimeStamp.ulSecond = 0x01020304;`) before the output code?  This will allow you to KNOW what should be there and have consistent and easy to interpret expected results as you test this.

Comment: @lbeh You may be clobbering the `.ulSecond` value somewhere else in code.  Maybe other part of your code is using this memory or maybe you're pointer is wrong and you're using the wrong memory here and in the assignment, but the other values just happen to not be getting overwritten.

Comment: @nategoose You were right, actually I just noticed I wasnt passing the function ExtEEPROM_Write(LOG_ENTRY_TYPE* pPtr), the address of the temporary variable I dequeue'd my log off to, i was passing it just the variable.  Thanks a lot for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type#C.2FC.2B.2B) and you can access the same data in multiple ways:

```
typedef union
{
    struct {
        UInt32 ulSecond;
        UInt16 usMilliSecond;
        UInt16 usPowerCycleCount;
    };
    UInt8 byte[8];
}
TIMESTAMP_TYPE;

int main() {
    TIMESTAMP_TYPE T;
    T.ulSecond = 1;
    T.usMilliSecond = 2;
    T.usPowerCycleCount = 3;
    printf("sizeof(T) = %ld\n", sizeof(T));
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("T[%d] = 0x%2.2X\n", i, T.byte[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
sizeof(T) = 8
T[0] = 0x01
T[1] = 0x00
T[2] = 0x00
T[3] = 0x00
T[4] = 0x02
T[5] = 0x00
T[6] = 0x03
T[7] = 0x00
```

Beware that the bytes array has native [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If that is not the desired endianness you will have to swap bytes around.

Comment: Thanks, Ill keep heading the union direction then.  Thanks for the help, tried to upvote you but not a high enough reputation... Thanks again

Comment: You ignore the desired endianness of the multi-byte values.

Comment: yes. that just gives you the native endianness. conversions are required if native endianness is not the desired one